# Tkinter Combobox. Как задать пустое значение

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, combobox

Если не указывать в `Combobox` значение по умолчанию и вывести его, то выведется `-1`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
combo.pack()
print(combo.current())

# Вывод: -1
```

Я могу спокойно указать в качестве значения по умолчанию имеющееся значение, допустим на 0

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
combo.pack()
combo.current(0)
print(combo.current())

# Выводится 0
```

Но как мне установить значение `-1`, если строка `combo.current(-1)` выдает ошибку?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
combo.pack()
combo.current(0)
print(combo.current())
combo.current(-1)
print(combo.current())

root.mainloop()

# Выдает ошибку
```

Answer (score 0):

Кроме выбора элементов из списка, `combobox` также позволяет вводить/задавать непосредственное значение (метод `set()`). Когда вы меняете (выбираете) `current()`, одновременно меняется и это значение (можете посмотреть при помощи метода `get()`). Т.к. изначально вы значение не задаёте, то оно равно пустой строке. Так что просто поставьте его снова в "пусто" и получите `-1`.

```
combo.current(0)
print(combo.current(), combo.get())
combo.set("")
print(combo.current(), combo.get())
combo.set("Not in the list")
print(combo.current(), combo.get())
```

```
0 1
-1
-1 Not in the list
```